# How to recovery source python code (.py) from .pyo file?

Tags: python, wxpython, extension-methods, decompiling

I need to convert a compiled python code (.pyo) to its source . I look in depython.net, but there is a problem. A warning;

"File version older than 2.4."

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: if this is your own code, then use a version control system in the future!

Answer (score 10):

try these:

[uncompyle2](https://github.com/Mysterie/uncompyle2) converts Python byte-code back into equivalent Python source code. It accepts byte-code from Python version 2.5 to 2.7. Additionally, it will only run on Python 2.7.

[uncompyle6](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6)  translates Python bytecode back into equivalent Python source code. It accepts bytecodes from Python version `1.5` to `3.7` or so including Pypy-generated bytecode. The code requires Python 2.4 or later and has been tested on Python running versions `2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6`.

Comment: I had the same issue and this helped. The documentation is a little misleading and mostly talked about .pyc files but it worked fine with my .pyo file.

Comment: @Arjun : When you write "The documentation is a little misleading and mostly talked about .pyc", if you can point me to where it mislead you, I will revise. Or better, suggest a revision.

Comment: @rocky the documentation for uncompyle6 looks great! Thanks for looking into it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [**decompyle**](http://www.crazy-compilers.com/decompyle/).

This has become a commercial service.
To experiment with it you can use [Debian Packages](http://packages.debian.org/sid/decompyle).

I would have loved to try it but I am on a windows machine. I will try it as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: I can't understand the DebianPackages method. I also use windows, so I need a virtual workstation like VMware, but its so complicated. I can't get rid of it.

Is there another method? Anyone who knows decompyling, if u help me I m really grateful. 
Thanks.

Comment: Try Ubuntu on Sun Virtual box. Its free and it works and its easy :)

Comment: I will try. thanks for your concern. I hope, I do it. Have a nice day.:)

Answer (score 1):

there is [Decompile](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/J.P.Giddy/python/decompiler/decompiler.html), the reputed cheap (but you can test it online) [depython](http://www.depython.net/) and the [UnPyc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unpyc/) project (is only for 2.5 <=). Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211/free-python-decompiler-that-is-not-an-online-service) is another SO-Question related to this.

I hope it helps.